# Calculation with input text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Helloooo

I just want to know how I can do to multiply a value that is in an input text by another value that is in an input text too.

I've tried it like this :

```
<div id="b" name="b">
<p id="bouz" name="bouz">Diameter (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="test" name="test" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
<p id="wtf" name="wtf">Width (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="zoubi" name="zoubi" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
</div>
</body>
<div id="c" name="c"><input type="text" id="c" name="c" onblur="calculvente()"></div>
<script>
let abc = document.getElementsById("test").value
let bac = document.getElementsById("zoubi").value
let cab = abc * bac
var select=document.getElementsById('cab')[0];
var input=document.getElementById('c');
select.onchange=function(){
  input.value=select.value[select.selectedId].text;
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why... If someone can explain how tf I can do that with javascript it would help me a lot. Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to call a function named calculvente()
so you need the function

```
function calculvente()
{
let abc = document.getElementsById("test").value
let bac = document.getElementsById("zoubi").value
let cab = abc * bac
document.getElementsById("c").value=cab
}
```

you also give the div and the input the same id. That cant work

```
<div id="b" name="b">
<p>Diameter (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="test" name="test" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
<p>Width (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="zoubi" name="zoubi" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
</div>
</body>
<div><input type="text" id="c" name="c" onblur="calculvente()"></div>
```

New try:

```
<div>
<p>Diameter (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="val1" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
<p>Width (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="val2" onblur="calculvente()"></p>

</div>

<div><input type="text" id="c" name="c"></div>

<script>
function calculvente(){
let abc = document.getElementById("val1").value
let bac = document.getElementById("val2").value
let cab = abc * bac
var input=document.getElementById('c');
input.value=cab;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ty for the answer but still don't work... 

<div id="b" name="b">
<p>Diameter (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="test" name="test" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
<p>Width (mm):</p> <p><input type="text" id="zoubi" name="zoubi" onblur="calculvente()"></p>
</div>
</body>

<script src="./script3.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" id="c" name="c" onblur="calculvente()"></div>
<script>
function calculvente() {
let abc = document.getElementsById("test").value
let bac = document.getElementsById("zoubi").value
let cab = abc * bac
document.getElementsById("c").value=cab
}
</script>

Comment: onblur means that the function starts if you loose the focus on the element. You have 3 Inputs, if you write a number in Input1 (ID Test) and Input2 (ID zobi) then you have get Input1*Input2 in the third input (Id c)

Comment: the new code upside works, the button you can delete if your not need it

Comment: I tried with  document.getElementsById("c").value=test * zoubi  but don't work I don't know why it sill don't work

Comment: I change my answer, the new code works in my browser. But its starts calculate after leave the second or first input. your need to change getElementsById to getElementById

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen for the inputs with `oninput` and update the your `c` input field:

```js
function calculvente() {
  let abc = parseInt(document.getElementById("test").value);
  let bac = parseInt(document.getElementById("zoubi").value);
  let cab = abc * bac;
  document.getElementById('result').value = cab;
}
```

```html
<div id="b" name="b">
  <p id="bouz" name="bouz">Diameter (mm):</p>
  <p><input oninput="calculvente()" type="number" id="test" name="test"></p>
  <p id="wtf" name="wtf">Width (mm):</p>
  <p><input oninput="calculvente()" type="number" id="zoubi" name="zoubi"></p>
</div>
<div id="c" name="c"><input type="text" id="result" name="result" readonly></div>
```